# Proxmox Active Directory AcceptSecurityContext Error

Tags: active-directory, ldap, proxmox

### Overview

I'm trying to get Proxmox to perform user authentication via LDAP with a Windows Server 2016 ADDS server. Proxmox is convinced that my credentials are incorrect.

### Environment

- Proxmox 6.3-1, PVE 6.3-6
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 1809, b17763.1823
- The Proxmox server and Domain Controller are on the same network (the DC is a guest on the Proxmox instance).
- The DC's root certificate has been added to the Proxmox server's store.
- Proxmox's realm binding is set up with a dedicated standard user account in the OU `OU=Service Users,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld`.
- I have an administrative account in the standard `CN=Users,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld`.
- Proxmox's realm binding is as follows via the GUI:

  ```
  General
  ---
  Domain: DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld
  Default: True
  Server: dc.subdomain.domain.tld
  Fallback Server: Unused
  Port: Default
  SSL: True
  Verify Certificate: True
  Require TFA: None

  Sync Options
  ---
  Bind User: CN=ServiceAccount,OU=Service Users,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld
  E-Mail Attribute: mail
  Groupname Attr.: sAMAccountName
  User Classes: user
  Group Classes: group
  User Filter: (&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf=CN=InfrastructureAdmins,CN=Users,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=tld))
  Group Filter: (sAMAccountName=InfrastructureAdmins)
  ```

### What's Happening

- Proxmox's login page gives the error message "Login failed. Please try again".
- Proxmox's syslog shows the line entry `hostname pvedaemon[pid]: authentication failure; rhost=10.9.0.50 user=username@realm msg=80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090439, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563`.

  - The error code `52e` suggests that the password is incorrect.
- I'm not seeing any entries for ServiceAccount or username in the DC's security event log when the login fails.

### What I've Tried

- I've verified that Proxmox can communicate with the DC; when the realm is synced, it successfully pulls groups and users from the domain.
- I've verified that the binding user `ServiceAccount` can log in to a domain-joined computer.
- I've verified that the account I'm testing with (my admin account) can log in to domain-joined computers; it's the account I'm logged into the DC with.

  - I've also created a test account with no additional settings, just the proper group membership, and attempted to use it to log into Proxmox.
- I've tried simplifying the passwords for both my user account and the binding account down to `P4$$w0rd`.
- LDAP works for other systems with a similar binding account.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100% sure this is due to the AD group 'Service Accounts' containing a space, which is allowed by design for MS AD groups, whereas Proxmox does not accept this.

**Work-around:**

Don't use the native AD group 'Service Accounts' (or any other group containing spaces for that matter) but substitute them for groups without spaces in their names.

**Solution:**

Hopefully an update from Proxmox which is now requested as a feature, but should imho be a prioritized bug fix, as to comply with the AD naming conventions used by Microsoft and open source variants that already do mimic these naming conventions (i.e. where a space is allowed).

See the following posts dating back to August 2020:

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/group-names-and-active-directory-sync.74072/

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/ldap-sync-with-nested-groups.80749/

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/ad-group-users-permissions-not-right.113395/

And the corresponding feature/bug request:

https://bugzilla.proxmox.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2929

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure you and I have the same problem, but I solved the same symptoms by:

- Ensure the 'domain' in the LDAP settings is the actual AD domain name (eg. `ad.example.com`). Proxmox will append this to a user name in order to log on, so the LDAP server will reject you if you've got it wrong.
- Ensure the user or group logging on has a Role assigned to them. You can do this by going to Datacentre->Permissions (the "title", not the things inside the pull-down!) and add a Group Permission (in my case, I used the LDAP group I'd created called `ProxmoxAdmins` and assigned it the `Administrator` role)

Things I've noticed are that the log messages don't tell you the cause of the problem at all. I've also noticed that LDAP groups cannot have spaces in them (eg. `Proxmox Admins` doesn't work, `ProxmoxAdmins` does). You can see this if you do a "sync preview" in the LDAP settings). And lastly, just because "sync" works, doesn't mean users will - it only tests the Bind credentials (a useful check, but not everything!).